# Can I change Replaykit language?

Tags: ios, swift, alert, replaykit

I use record screen with replaykit. How can I change language of this alert. Or can I make my own custom alert view?

[image]

Comment: which language do you want to change?

Comment: sorry... Swift 2 please.  turkish language. @DeeprajChowrasia

Answer (score 0):

You  add `InfoPlist.strings` file to localise values of `Info.plist`.  open  `File->New->File`, choose `Strings File` under `Resource` tab of `iOS`, name  `InfoPlist`,  create.  insert the `Info.plist` values you want to localise like your current recording allowstring

Answer (score 0):

It's a framework of **apple**;as per my knowledge we can't use custom alert in this case. It should have been working if we change the language of the device, but sadly it's not changing the language of the alert of the `ReplayKit`.May be it's an issue of **Apple** itself.